# Fetch_status in Teradata

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, teradata

@@
I am using cursors in Teradata and I need some help related to fetch_status

below are the SQL Server FETCH_STATUS values

Return value Description
0 FETCH statement was successful.
-1 FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set.
-2 Row fetched is missing.

Can you tell me the equivalent values for the FETCH_STATUS in Teradata

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are iterating through a cursor using `FETCH` the `SQLCODE` and `SQLSTATE` will be set accordingly when you have exceeded the records in the resultset.

- `SQLCODE` is set to 7362
- `SQLSTATE` is set to ‘02000’

The system will handle this error internally allowing you to write your loop logic in a similar manner:

```
OPEN myCursor;

WHILE (SQLCODE = 0)
  FETCH myCursor INTO Field1, Field2;
END WHILE;

CLOSE myCursor;
```